# RAD8 and WAS8.5 configuration setting: RAD 8 does not showing WAS 8.5 server adapters to adding new server

Tags: websphere

Hi I have installed RAD 8. and I have installed WAS8.5. But when I am adding new server in RAD WAS8.5 is not showing. So I have to install server adapter for WAS8.5 right? I have tried to install WAS8.5 server adapter in RADv8. It is giving option only upto WAS version 8. how can I setup WAS8.5 server in RAD 8. Please explain me step by step. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

RAD 8.0 is too old - see [System requirements](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27019500#Servers). You will need at least 8.5 for this, but better go for 9.0.